# getting error when running this. For record im very new to coding and wanted to try this small idea i have. Just having problems on the last few lines

Tags: python

So all the code runs well up until the final line or so. I want it to take the sum of all the inputs when asking for the price of each item

```
number_of_items = int(input('How many items do you have: '))
x = 0


if number_of_items == 0:
    print('Are you not buying anything? ')
elif number_of_items > 10:
print('Sorry we only accept 10 items or less')
else:

    while x < number_of_items:
        x += 1
        sum_ = int(input(f'Cost of item {x}: '))
        print(sum(sum_))
```

I tried to use
print(sum(sum_)
with sum_ being my variable that holds the values of the inputed cost of the items

I expected it to take the sum of all the items but it did not.

So im like really new. Like I only know the basics of. If statements, and For and While loops. and obviously anything basic for that. So if you could not solve the problem I have but maybe just point me in the right direction that would be awesome, thanks.

Comment: Right now you're assigning each individual cost to the `sum_` variable then immediately printing it out. You should instead assign the individual costs to a `cost` variable then accumulate each of those in a `sum_` variable and print it out _after_ the loop has ended. Much like `x += 1`, do `sum_ += cost`.

Comment: Think of Stack Overflow like a FAQ, not a forum -- questions should be focused on describing a problem in such a way that someone else with the same problem can efficiently find your question in search results and learn from its answers; that means writing the question, and its title in particular, to focus on a specific technical issue, not on the personal circumstances in which you encountered that issue. (For further background, see [Stack Overflow: The Wikipedia of Long-Tail Programming Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/))

Comment: ...so, instead of just saying your program "did not" achieve your goal -- what _did_ it do instead? Focus on the bug itself, taking out parts that work to focus only on the parts that don't (so if input works fine, you don't need to include `input()` calls and can just hardcode the values that the user would have entered; the intent is to have a [mre] that's the shortest thing someone else could possibly run to see the same problem).

Answer (score 1):

Change your answer to this:

```
number_of_items = int(input('How many items do you have: '))


if number_of_items == 0:
    print('Are you not buying anything? ')
elif number_of_items > 10:
    print('Sorry we only accept 10 items or less')
else:
    # use a total variable so you don't change it every time
    sum = 0
    # use a for loop because you it keeps track of the iterable for you already
    for i in range(number_of_items):
        sum += int(input(f'Cost of item {i + 1}: '))
    # convert the int to a string. that's why u had an error
    print(f"Sum is ${str(sum)}")
```